# Electromagnetic Induction. The electric field due to a conducting loop in a changing magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetic-induction

What is the developed *electric field* when a conducting loop is placed in a magnetic field that varies with time ? I know that an emf is generated in the loop due to which current flows through it but what is the electric field ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the integral Maxwell-Faraday equation, the induced electric field $E$ in a circular conducting loop (radius  $R$, area $A$) in a varying perpendicular homogeneous magnetic field $B$  is given by $$E=\frac{\int \vec E d\vec r}{2\pi R} =\frac{-A\frac {dB}{dt}}{2\pi R}=-\frac{R}{2}\frac{dB}{dt}$$